# Hacked Joomla 3.1 administrator login page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.1

My website was hacked, and i can see login page on my joomla administrator login page

here is the url of login page:

```
http://societ.us/administrator/index.php
```

the hacker was add code (at line 13-15):

```
  <style type="text/css">
html { display:none }
  </style>
```

Do you know how to remove that code?

I have checked few file below (and many more), and i haven't found it

in /home/societ/societ.us/administrator/templates/isis/login.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  Templates.isis
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

// Add Stylesheets
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' .$this->template. '/css/template.css');

// Load optional RTL Bootstrap CSS
JHtml::_('bootstrap.loadCss', false, $this->direction);

// Load specific language related CSS
$file = 'language/' . $lang->getTag() . '/' . $lang->getTag() . '.css';
if (is_file($file))
{
    $doc->addStyleSheet($file);
}

// Detecting Active Variables
$option   = $app->input->getCmd('option', '');
$view     = $app->input->getCmd('view', '');
$layout   = $app->input->getCmd('layout', '');
$task     = $app->input->getCmd('task', '');
$itemid   = $app->input->getCmd('Itemid', '');
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');

// Check if debug is on
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$debug  = (boolean) $config->get('debug');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>" >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEvent('domready', function ()
        {
            document.getElementById('form-login').username.select();
            document.getElementById('form-login').username.focus();
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Responsive Styles */
        @media (max-width: 480px) {
            .view-login .container {
                margin-top: -170px;
            }
            .btn {
                font-size: 13px;
                padding: 4px 10px 4px;
            }
        }
        <?php if ($debug) : ?>
            .view-login .container {
                position: static;
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
            }
            .view-login .navbar-fixed-bottom {
                display: none;
            }
        <?php endif; ?>
    </style>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="site <?php echo $option . " view-" . $view . " layout-" . $layout . " task-" . $task . " itemid-" . $itemid . " ";?>">
    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Begin Content -->
            <div id="element-box" class="login well">
                <img src="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template ?>/images/joomla.png" alt="Joomla!" />
                <hr />
                <jdoc:include type="message" />
                <jdoc:include type="component" />
            </div>
            <noscript>
                <?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_WARNJAVASCRIPT') ?>
            </noscript>
            <!-- End Content -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom hidden-phone">
        <p class="pull-right">&copy; <?php echo $sitename; ?> <?php echo date('Y');?></p>
        <a class="login-joomla" href="http://www.joomla.org" class="hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JHtml::tooltipText('TPL_ISIS_ISFREESOFTWARE');?>">Joomla!&#174;</a>
        <a href="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>" class="pull-left"><i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> <?php echo JText::_('COM_LOGIN_RETURN_TO_SITE_HOME_PAGE') ?></a>
    </div>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" style="none" />
</body>
</html>
```

in /home/societ/societ.us/administrator/templates/isis/index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Administrator
 * @subpackage  Templates.isis
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 * @since       3.0
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$app   = JFactory::getApplication();
$doc   = JFactory::getDocument();
$lang  = JFactory::getLanguage();
$this->language = $doc->language;
$this->direction = $doc->direction;
$input = $app->input;
$user  = JFactory::getUser();

// Add JavaScript Frameworks
JHtml::_('bootstrap.framework');
$doc->addScript('templates/' .$this->template. '/js/template.js');

// Add Stylesheets
$doc->addStyleSheet('templates/' . $this->template . '/css/template.css');

// Load optional RTL Bootstrap CSS
JHtml::_('bootstrap.loadCss', false, $this->direction);

// Load specific language related CSS
$file = 'language/' . $lang->getTag() . '/' . $lang->getTag() . '.css';
if (is_file($file))
{
    $doc->addStyleSheet($file);
}

// Detecting Active Variables
$option   = $input->get('option', '');
$view     = $input->get('view', '');
$layout   = $input->get('layout', '');
$task     = $input->get('task', '');
$itemid   = $input->get('Itemid', '');
$sitename = $app->getCfg('sitename');

$cpanel = ($option === 'com_cpanel');

$showSubmenu = false;
$this->submenumodules = JModuleHelper::getModules('submenu');
foreach ($this->submenumodules as $submenumodule)
{
    $output = JModuleHelper::renderModule($submenumodule);
    if (strlen($output))
    {
        $showSubmenu = true;
        break;
    }
}

// Logo file
if ($this->params->get('logoFile'))
{
    $logo = JUri::root() . $this->params->get('logoFile');
}
else
{
    $logo = $this->baseurl . "/templates/" . $this->template . "/images/logo.png";
}

// Template Parameters
$displayHeader = $this->params->get('displayHeader', '1');
$statusFixed = $this->params->get('statusFixed', '1');
$stickyToolbar = $this->params->get('stickyToolbar', '1');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <jdoc:include type="head" />
    <?php
    // Template color
    if ($this->params->get('templateColor'))
    {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .navbar-inner, .navbar-inverse .navbar-inner, .dropdown-menu li > a:hover, .dropdown-menu .active > a, .dropdown-menu .active > a:hover, .navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle, #status.status-top
        {
            background: <?php echo $this->params->get('templateColor');?>;
        }
        .navbar-inner, .navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle, .navbar-inverse .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle{
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 30px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    // Template header color
    if ($this->params->get('headerColor'))
    {
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .header
        {
            background: <?php echo $this->params->get('headerColor');?>;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    }
    ?>

    <!-- Sidebar background color -->
    <?php if ($this->params->get('sidebarColor')) : ?>
    <style type="text/css">
        .nav-list > .active > a, .nav-list > .active > a:hover
        {
            background: <?php echo $this->params->get('sidebarColor'); ?>;
        }
    </style>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="../media/jui/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="admin <?php echo $option . " view-" . $view . " layout-" . $layout . " task-" . $task . " itemid-" . $itemid . " ";?>" <?php if ($stickyToolbar) : ?>data-spy="scroll" data-target=".subhead" data-offset="87"<?php endif;?>>
    <!-- Top Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <?php if ($this->params->get('admin_menus') != '0') : ?>
                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <a class="brand" href="<?php echo JUri::root(); ?>" title="<?php echo JText::sprintf('TPL_ISIS_PREVIEW', $sitename);?>" target="_blank"><?php echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $sitename, 14, false, false);?> <i class="icon-out-2 small"></i></a>
                <?php if ($this->params->get('admin_menus') != '0') : ?>
                <div class="nav-collapse">
                <?php else : ?>
                <div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu" style="none" />
                    <ul class="<?php if ($this->direction == 'rtl') : ?>nav<?php else : ?>nav pull-right<?php endif; ?>">
                        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><?php echo $user->name; ?> <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class=""><a href="index.php?option=com_admin&task=profile.edit&id=<?php echo $user->id;?>"><?php echo JText::_('TPL_ISIS_EDIT_ACCOUNT');?></a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li class=""><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_login&task=logout&'. JSession::getFormToken() .'=1');?>"><?php echo JText::_('TPL_ISIS_LOGOUT');?></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Header -->
    <?php
    if ($displayHeader):
    ?>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span2 container-logo">
                    <a class="logo" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo;?>" alt="<?php echo $sitename; ?>" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="span10">
                    <?php if (isset($app->JComponentTitle)) : ?>
                        <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $app->JComponentTitle, 0, false, false);?></h1>
                    <?php else : ?>
                        <h1 class="page-title"><?php echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', '', 0, false, false);?></h1>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <?php
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php
    if ((!$statusFixed) && ($this->countModules('status'))):
    ?>
    <!-- Begin Status Module -->
    <div id="status" class="navbar status-top hidden-phone">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="status" style="no" />
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Status Module -->
    <?php
    endif;
    ?>
    <?php
    if (!$cpanel):
    ?>
    <!-- Subheader -->
    <a class="btn btn-subhead" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".subhead-collapse"><?php echo JText::_('TPL_ISIS_TOOLBAR');?> <i class="icon-wrench"></i></a>
    <div class="subhead-collapse collapse">
        <div class="subhead">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div id="container-collapse" class="container-collapse"></div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="toolbar" style="no" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    else:
    ?>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 20px"></div>
    <?php
    endif;
    ?>
    <!-- container-fluid -->
    <div class="container-fluid container-main">
        <section id="content">
            <!-- Begin Content -->
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="top" style="xhtml" />
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <?php if ($showSubmenu) : ?>
                    <div class="span2">
                        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="submenu" style="none" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="span10">
                <?php else : ?>
                    <div class="span12">
                <?php endif; ?>
                        <jdoc:include type="message" />
                        <?php
                        // Show the page title here if the header is hidden
                        if (!$displayHeader):
                        ?>
                        <h1 class="content-title"><?php echo JHtml::_('string.truncate', $app->JComponentTitle, 0, false, false);?></h1>
                        <?php
                        endif;
                        ?>
                        <jdoc:include type="component" />
                    </div>
            </div>
            <?php if ($this->countModules('bottom')) : ?>
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom" style="xhtml" />
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- End Content -->
        </section>

        <?php if (!$this->countModules('status') || (!$statusFixed && $this->countModules('status'))) : ?>
            <footer class="footer">
                <p align="center">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="no" />
                &copy; <?php echo $sitename; ?> <?php echo date('Y');?></p>
            </footer>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (($statusFixed) && ($this->countModules('status'))) : ?>
    <!-- Begin Status Module -->
    <div id="status" class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom hidden-phone">
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <p><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="no" />
                &copy; <?php echo $sitename; ?> <?php echo date('Y');?></p>

            </div>
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="status" style="no" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Status Module -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="debug" style="none" />
    <?php if ($stickyToolbar) : ?>
    <script>
        (function($){
            // fix sub nav on scroll
            var $win = $(window)
              , $nav = $('.subhead')
              , navTop = $('.subhead').length && $('.subhead').offset().top - <?php if ($displayHeader || !$statusFixed) : ?>40<?php else:?>20<?php endif;?>
              , isFixed = 0

            processScroll()

            // hack sad times - holdover until rewrite for 2.1
            $nav.on('click', function ()
            {
                if (!isFixed) setTimeout(function () {  $win.scrollTop($win.scrollTop() - 47) }, 10)
            })

            $win.on('scroll', processScroll)

            function processScroll()
            {
                var i, scrollTop = $win.scrollTop()
                if (scrollTop >= navTop && !isFixed)
                {
                    isFixed = 1
                    $nav.addClass('subhead-fixed')
                } else if (scrollTop <= navTop && isFixed)
                {
                    isFixed = 0
                    $nav.removeClass('subhead-fixed')
                }
            }
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You In Advance

Comment: it will be in a template file, and looks more like a joke than a hack - easy to get around disable styles

Comment: Of course it is a joke. Any hacker with real intentions would do that in the front-end, not the back-end. Unless of course, they have planted a plugin that doesn't show this tag with certain $_GET values, and they want to be able to "take control" of the site later on.

Comment: Try removing '<jdoc:include type="head" />' from your code and see if the evil CSS is still there

Comment: @NickB: where is i can found '<jdoc:include type="head" />' source code?
So i can edit it and remove only that css

Comment: Assuming you removed that line from "isis/index.php", did the CSS still appear? See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be **injected** into  `<jdoc:include type="head" />`.

Try removing this line, for debugging purposes and see if the 'malicious' CSS is still present.

If not, then the code is infact injected into this Joomla include. To edit that file being called by Joomla, head over to:

```
/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php
```

and try searching for anything out of the ordinary.

If you for some reason don't want to manually fix this problem, try **re-installing** Joomla onto the already existing website ***(be-careful not to overwrite your current configs, database and template)***, which I'm sure will fix this problem.

Comment: Actually i dont found wanted code in that file,
but i will try to search more file thats included on head.php
Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see it in the files, neither can we...
There are hundreds of files that the hacker may have altered.

It seems as if it is something within the template, but it could be as simple as a plugin for the administrator.

Use the `Inspect Element` in Firefox or Chrome, and remove the HTML style. Login to your administrator, and keep on manually removing the HTML style, until you find out what the hacker did.

Comment: Or you can override the CSS.... which is a much more realistic way to fix this problem

Comment: The user seems to be unable to locate the CSS in the first place, and it is "hacked" *after* loading the template.css that he has.

Comment: @NickB - good idea, however if it were me, I would rather find the file causing the actual problem than a simple fix that could possibly be overridden in the future.

Comment: And, of course, he needs to find the hacker's entry point, and update to the latest version if he isn't already at it.